# Generic Class with NSObject inheritance, self.setValue(, forKey: ) not work

Tags: ios, swift, generics, nsobject

I want to set value direct in `NSObject` using self.setValue(, forKey: ) that time give me an error. [like that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue?language=objc)

> 2018-03-08 17:36:36.723485+0530 BaseProject[20631:312969] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtGC11BaseProject8DataRootCS_4Root_ 0x600000452840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key data.'

When I set the value using Generic T like `var data: [T] = []`  then app is crash, and I set Class name like `var data: [Root] = []` then work perfectly.

My Codes is

```
protocol AGMappable {
    init(with responseDict: [String: AnyObject])
}
```

My Model Class is

```
class Root: NSObject, AGMappable {
    var avatar: String = ""
    var id: Int = 0
    var first_name: String = ""
    var last_name: String = ""

    required init(with responseDict: [String: AnyObject]) {
        super.init()
        avatar = responseDict["avatar"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Set a value using setValue(,forKey:)

```
class DataRoot<T: AGMappable>: NSObject, AGMappable{
    var page: Int = 0
    var per_page: Int = 0
    var total: Int = 0
    var total_pages: Int = 0
    var data: [T] = []

    required init(with responseDict: [String: AnyObject]){
        super.init()
        if let datastr = responseDict["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            var temp: [T] = []
            for v in datastr {
                temp.append(T(with: v as [String: AnyObject]))
            }
            self.setValue(temp, forKey: "data") // Here error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to better understand the problem try using the correct way and see the error `setValue(temp, forKey: #keyPath(data))`

Answer (score 0):

`setValue(_:forKey:)` can work with `@objc` properties only, as it relies on runtime features that only `@objc` properties have. Swift 4 changed the way class members are available to Objective-C: they are no longer available by default, so you either need to declare the class as `@objcMembers`, or add `@objc` individually to every member you need to expose to Objective-C.

However in your case the class can't be exported to Objective-C due to the fact that is a generic one, so you need to declare `data` as `@objc var data: [T] = []`, or `dynamic var data: [T] = []`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it like this

```
    let datastr = responseDict["data"] as? [[String : Any]]
    self.data = datastr?.map {
        T(with: $0)
    } ?? [T]()
```

Comment: My requirement is to assign a value using self.setValue(,forKey:)

Comment: Can you use keyPaths? Like this `self[keyPath: \DataRoot.data] = temp`